# How do I extend Strapi admin panel API controller to update a field

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi

I have a requirement where I need to fetch duration of a video which comes from a third party API.

I have a videos collection type in Strapi, whenever a video is updated in Strapi admin panel, I want to fetch the duration from third party API and update the duration field.

I have written a controller in api>videos but it is not being called on admin panel update.

Please tell me how can I achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have described you may want to look at
Content-Type Hooks. According to this article (https://strapi.io/blog/understanding-the-different-types-categories-of-strapi-hooks).
These hooks allow us to extend Strapi's default Content-Type functionality by introducing custom code that will run whenever (before or after) a query is executed over a Content-Type.

In your case `afterCreate` method can be used to hit the third party API and then update field for video duration using Entity Service API as described here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service/crud.html#update